# Json_encode returns string instead of object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I got a php file that do some operations with the data and then send the data in `json` format(supposedly).

Then I receive the data in a js file, using ajax. It's a cross domain operation, then I need to use jsonp.

The trouble is that I'm receiving the error

> Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"} 
>   parsererror - Error: jQuery1123030211047915085665_1465277732410 was
>   not called(…)

which I believe that is because I'm not receiving the data as a json object but as a simple string(when I change datatype from jsonp to text it goes to the `.done` block).

What can I do to receive the data as a json object, not as a simple string?

Code:

php:

```
if ( $moeda ==='SEK' ){

 foreach($result as $r){ //$result is an array with the result of a sql query

//here I do some verifications, that depending on the circunstance, calculate and replace 
//the value of the $r['price'] field.

    if($r['currency'] === "SEK"){
        $valor = $r['tprice'];
        $r['tprice'] = number_format($valor,2,'.','');

    }else if ($r['currency'] === "BRL"){
        $dat = $r['emissao'];
        $valor = $r['tprice'];  
        $r['tprice'] = number_format( ( converteBRL_SEK($dat,$valor) ) ,2,'.','');


    }else if ($r['currency'] === "USD"){
        $dat = $r['emissao'];
        $valor = $r['tprice'];
        $r['tprice'] = number_format(( converteUSD_SEK($dat,$valor) ),2,'.','');     

    }else if ($r['currency'] === "EUR"){
        $dat = $r['emissao'];
        $valor = $r['tprice'];
            $r['tprice'] = number_format(( converteEUR_SEK($dat,$valor) ),2,'.','');    

    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
$retorno['dados'] = $r;   
// using the GET callback because I'm using jsonp.
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).')'; 


}
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot to post the javascript code, here goes:

code:

```
function buildTableDetail(p_sts,p_ar){  
    $('#tb_detail').empty();
    return $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       crossDomain:true,
       url:'http://localhost/files/montar_detail_local.php?callback=?',// I use a real url, localhost just for the example
       dataType:'jsonp',
       data: {area:p_ar,
              st:p_sts},
       beforeSend: function(){
       $('#t_detail').css('opacity','1.0');  
           console.log(p_ar);
        console.log(p_sts);
       }    


    }).done(function(data){
        //after I get the data, I build a table, and format some values here...
         $('#tb_detail').empty();

         console.log("AREA:"+p_ar);
         for (i = 0; i < data.dados.length; i++) { 
             $('#tb_detail').append('<tr> <td>'+data.dados[i].proposal+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail old_no" >'+data.dados[i].old_no+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail emissao" style="white-space: nowrap;">'+data.dados[i].emissao+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail area">'+data.dados[i].area+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail country">'+data.dados[i].country+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail ec_name">'+data.dados[i].ec_name+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail distributo">'+data.dados[i].distributo+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail project">'+data.dados[i].project+
                                    '</td><td>'+float2moeda(data.dados[i].tprice)+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail gm">'+data.dados[i].gm+
                                    '</td><td >'+data.dados[i].prob+
                                    '</td><td class="h_detail st">'+(data.dados[i].st).substr(0,1)+'</td></tr>');


                console.log(data.dados[i].proposal);
                console.log(data.dados[i].distributo);
            }
})
.fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Erro na operação.");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
     })

}
```

**EDIT2:**

Just updated this line:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).')';
```

to this

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).');';
```

and the error is not showing anymore. However, it's not entering in the `for` loop and it's not showing any data. I used `console.log(data.dados.lenght)` and it returns 'undefined' to me, so I can't loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to post the javascript as well.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
  if ( $moeda ==='SEK' ){

 foreach($result as $r){ //$result is an array with the result of a sql query

//here I do some verifications, that depending on the circunstance, calculate and replace 
//the value of the $r['price'] field.

    if($r['currency'] === "SEK"){
        $valor = $r['tprice'];
        $r['tprice'] = number_format($valor,2,'.','');

    }else if ($r['currency'] === "BRL"){
        $dat = $r['emissao'];
        $valor = $r['tprice'];  
        $r['tprice'] = number_format( ( converteBRL_SEK($dat,$valor) ) ,2,'.','');


    }else if ($r['currency'] === "USD"){
        $dat = $r['emissao'];
        $valor = $r['tprice'];
        $r['tprice'] = number_format(( converteUSD_SEK($dat,$valor) ),2,'.','');     

    }else if ($r['currency'] === "EUR"){
        $dat = $r['emissao'];
        $valor = $r['tprice'];
            $r['tprice'] = number_format(( converteEUR_SEK($dat,$valor) ),2,'.','');    

    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
$retorno['dados'][] = $r;   //append to the array

}
   // using the GET callback because I'm using jsonp.
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).');'; //echo the valid call of the callback
```

Comment: Will try here and answer in a minute

Comment: Hey, thanks! it solved half of the problem! **I'm not receiving the error anymore** BUT it returns nothing to me. No information comes

Comment: when you console data what do you receive?

Comment: I receive just one registry, but it have to come far more than just one

Comment: how does your xhr response body look like?

Comment: do you mean the response in the console?

Comment: Thanks man! I updated as you said and worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry to bother but, I tried to upload the code in the server I use it, but it doesn't work. It worked on localhost, but not in the real server :(

Comment: change the url in the ajax to the url of the host

Comment: yes I changed, it's like this: `http://www.myurl.com.br/api/my_php.php?callback=?'` but it returned to shout me that inicial error

Answer (score 2):

JSON is nothing but a string. Please use $.parseJSON in javascript if you are using jQuery to convert the json string to object.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I had to do others data operations between server and client using json_encode and it received as Json object normally. Including this example. It's started to shout this error right after I wrote the if's and doing the conversions. Before that, I was just doing a sql query, fetching to an array, then using json_encode to send the data as `json` object and it was working

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` instead `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`.

something like this.

`echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($retorno,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT).')';`

Comment: Hi, I already tried, but it doesn't worked. It's keeps shouting the same error

Comment: did you try to using `dataType:'json',` instead of `dataType:'jsonp',`

Comment: Yes, it's gives me a Cross Domain error. It's a cross domain operation, then I have to use jsonp. json doesn't work for me in this situation

Comment: in your .htaccess add this `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` and try to use json.

Comment: if you look closely you can see he's on localhost and in his brwoser he has 127.0.0.1 and in the ajax he is ajaxing localhost not 127.0.0.1 this is causing the CORS error

Comment: @madalinivascu yes i know, but yesterday i was also working on localhost  and was getting CORS error using `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` I've solved my error and because of the way i was executing my code i should get CORS error.